# Django sorting by a category and pagination combining both in one function view

Tags: python, html, django

I'm trying to sort my projects by categories: all, css, HTML, Django, and so on. and also trying to add pagination when showing all projects have a limit of 6 projects per page. I'm stuck and have trouble combining either the pagination work or the filter/ sorting the items work, here's my code. Please Help :)

models.py

```
class Category (models.Model):

    category_name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-category_name',)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.category_name
    
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('mainpages:project_by_category', args=[self.slug])


class Project(models.Model):

    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default='', null=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField()
    technology = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    proj_url = models.URLField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    blog_link = models.URLField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    image = models.ImageField(default='post-img.jpg', upload_to='proj-img')

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-title',)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

view.py

```
def portfolioView(request, category_slug=None):

    # added
    category = None
    categories = Category.objects.all()
    # filtering by project
    projs = Project.objects.all()

    # paginator added
    projects = Project.objects.all()
    paginator = Paginator(projects, 3)
    page = request.GET.get('page')
    try:
        projects = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        projects = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        projects = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

    # added
    if category_slug:
        category = get_object_or_404(Category, slug=category_slug)
        projs = projs.filter(category=category)
    # 
    
    return render(request, 'mainpages/portfolio.html', {
        'category': category,
        'categories': categories,
        'projects': projects,
        'page': page,
        'projs': projs,
    })


def projectDetail(request, pk):

    project = Project.objects.get(pk=pk)
    context = {
        'project': project
    }
    return render(request, 'mainpages/portfolio-detail.html', context)
```

pagination.html

```html
<div class="pagination">
    <span class="step-links">
    {% if page.has_previous %}
        <a href="?page={{ page.previous_page_number }}">Previous</a>
        {% endif %}
    <span class="current">
        Page {{ page.number }} of {{ page.paginator.num_pages }}
    </span>
        {% if page.has_next %}
        <a href="?page={{ page.next_page_number }}">Next</a>
    </span>
        {% endif %}
</div>
```

porftfolio.html

```html
{% extends 'mainpages/base.html' %}
{% load static %}  
{% block content %}

      <!--  -->
       <section class="portfolio-section">
        <!--  -->
        <div class="portfolio-info">
          <h1>PORTFOLIO</h1>
          <p>Industry's so electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop</p>
        </div>
        <!--  -->
        <div class="category-container">
          <div class="category-wrapper">
            <div class="category-title">
              <h3>Catergories</h3>
            </div>
            

            <!--  -->
            <div class="category-links">
              <ul>
                <li><a href="{% url 'mainpages:portfolio' %}">ALL</a></li>

                {% for c in categories %}
                <li>
                  <a href="{{ c.get_absolute_url }}">{{ c.category_name}}</a>
                </li>
                {% endfor %}
              </ul>
            </div>

            <div>
              <h1>
                {% if category %}
                  <p class="center-category">All {{ category.category_name }} Projects</p>
                {% else %}
                  <p class="center-category">All Projects</p>
                {% endif %}
              </h1>
              {% for p in project %}
                <a href="{% url 'mainpages:portfolio-detail' project.pk %}">{{ p.title }}</a>
              {% endfor %}
            </div>

            <!--  -->
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="work-container">
          <div class="work-wrapper">
            {% for project in projects %}
            <div class="work-links">
              <div class="card">
                <img class="work-img" src="{{ project.image.url }}" alt="">
                <h6 class="title">{{ project.title }}</h6>
                <span> {{ project.description |truncatechars:50 }}</span>
                <button class="works-btn">
                     <a href="{% url 'mainpages:portfolio-detail' project.pk %}">View Project</a>
                </button>
              </div>
            </div>
            {% endfor %}
          </div>
        </div>

      {% include 'mainpages/pagination.html' with page=projects %}

  </section>
    
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: First you need to get the projects whose category is the same as the received one, then do the pagination with those records.

Comment: lol, I'm sorry but I was all day trying to figure out how would you fix it, is it in the views.py?